# Pre-defined Length List of Lists

Tags: apex, array

Per [the docs on Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm), I can use array notation to create a list of pre-allocated length:

```
List<String> colors = new String[1];
```

However, replacing the primitive String type with a list doesn't work, but produces `unexpected token: '['`:

```
List<List<String>> colorLists = new List<String>[1]; // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Further exploration shows that you also can't use bracket notation without a fixed size:

```
List<List<String>> colorLists = new List<String>[]; // ALSO DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Specifically, the docs state, "... you can declare a one-dimensional list of primitives or objects by following the data type name with the [] characters."   So are collections not considered "objects", is this a bug, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax changes slightly when you use the parameterized syntax:

```
List<List<String>> colorLists = new List<List<String>>(1);
```

If you want the list to be empty, do not provide a parameter (or use 0):

```
List<List<String>> colorLists = new List<List<String>>(0);
```

`[]` is syntactic sugar, but it doesn't always work. For example, you can't write two-dimensional lists like this:

```
String[][] colorLists; // DOES NOT COMPILE
List<String>[] colorLists; // ALSO DOES NOT COMPILE
```

But you can make the inner list using `[]`:

```
List<String[]> colorLists = new List<String[]>(0);
```

It's really quite an annoyance, especially coming from a C/C++/Java background like myself, but it's just a matter of syntax.

The docs kind of hint at this by saying:

> Using Array Notation for One-Dimensional Lists

That is, you can use the shorthand notation for one-dimension lists, but not for multi-dimensional lists of any combination.